# npm install ts-md5 ERROR

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I'm getting an error everytime I execute `npm install ts-md5` command in node.js command prompt. I have no idea hoe to resolve this problem. Hope you can help me, thanks in advance Here is the error:

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>npm install ts-md5
C:\Users\Administrator
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@*
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1
`-- ts-md5@1.2.2

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Administrator\
package.json'
npm WARN @ionic-native/network@4.1.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.
0 || >=4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/network@4.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none
 was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/network@4.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was
 installed.
npm WARN Administrator No description
npm WARN Administrator No repository field.
npm WARN Administrator No README data
npm WARN Administrator No license field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that package.json is missing.
You can use : `npm install` only inside npm project.
Create a new folder and execute `npm init` on it and follow the instructions.

Comment: thanks, I try to run it inside a project but I still get two npm warning.

Comment: this is the warning: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"
})